# Django: required field even with true=blank on form submision

Tags: html, django

I've a form that has a field 'instrucciones' that should be optional to complete. I've tried to modified it in the model and put it as a blank field, null true, and even use a default ('').

instrucciones = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default='')

However, in submition I'm ask to complete this field. Why?

[image]

**models.py:**

```
class TamaniosCantidades(models.Model):
    TAMANIOS = (('2x2', '2" x 2"',), ('3x3', '3" x 3"',),
               ('4x4', '4" x 4"',), ('5x5', '5" x 5"',))

    CANTIDADES = (('50', '50',), ('100', '100',),
                ('150', '150',))

    # usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    tamanios = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TAMANIOS)
    cantidades = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CANTIDADES)
    imagenes = models.FileField(upload_to='imagenes/', null=True)
    instrucciones = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    # uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tamanios
```

**forms.py**

```
# Declare Forms
class StepOneForm(forms.Form):
    tamanios = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TAMANIOS, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label='Selecciona un tamaño')
    cantidades = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CANTIDADES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label='Selecciona la cantidad')



class StepThreeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    instrucciones = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    class Meta:
        model = TamaniosCantidades
        fields = ('imagenes', 'instrucciones')
```

**html:**

{% csrf_token %}

```
            <div class="form-group">

                {{ form.imagenes|as_crispy_field }}

                <div id="instrucciones-adicionales"  style="display: none">

                    <p class="bold-font"> Instrucciones adicionales (opcional):</p>

                    {{ form.instrucciones|as_crispy_field }}

                </div>
            </div>


            </br>
            </br>

            <p>O, sáltate este paso y envía tu arte por correo electrónico</p>


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-naranja text-white btn-block">Continuar
            </button>


        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your form underneath class Meta:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StepThreeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['instrucciones'].required  = False
```

You can also use this method to add other attributes to your fields:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StepThreeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['instrucciones'].required  = False
    self.fields['instrucciones'].label  = 'Instrucciones'
    self.fields['instructions'].help_text = 'Give instructions.'
```

You can even use it to get request in your form:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
    super(StepThreeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

But you must also pass the request to the view:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(ViewName, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['request'] = self.request
    return kwargs
```

Comment: Ty. Would you describe or post a link for further investigation on this?

Comment: @OmarGonzales - I don't have a link handy, but what I recommend is to download the Django docs for your version and save it on your desktop. Then by searching command F self.init you should be able to get examples for other ways the method is used. I'll edit the post to show other ways you can use this method.